# Debugging mysql too many connections problem

Tags: mysql, database

I get a "too many connections" error from time to time with my mysql database, if I do a

```
show status like 'Conn%';
```

I get a result like this

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Connections   | 291   | 
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but if I look at the processlist with

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

I only see a few real connections

```
+-----+---------+------------------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id  | User    | Host                         | db      | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+-----+---------+------------------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
|  28 | www     | webhost01:38876              | webapp  | Sleep   |    2 |       | NULL                      | 
|  29 | www     | webhost01:53322              | webapp  | Sleep   |    2 |       | NULL                      | 
|  30 | www     | webhost01:45583              | webapp  | Sleep   |    2 |       | NULL                      | 
|  31 | www     | webhost01:35779              | webapp  | Sleep   |    2 |       | NULL                      | 
|  32 | www     | webhost01:49122              | webapp  | Sleep   |    2 |       | NULL                      | 
|  36 | root    | localhost                    | NULL    | Query   |    0 | NULL  | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST     | 
| 126 | stats   | localhost                    | stats   | Sleep   | 1056 |       | NULL                      | 
+-----+---------+------------------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
```

How can I see all connections? I suspect that some applications don't close their connections, how can I debug/prevent this?

Comment: How do I run these commands if I already have too many connections? If I try to launch mysql I once again get "too many connections".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SHOW STATUS` value that you want to look at is [`Threads_connected`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_connected). Because [`Connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections) shows only the accumulated number of connections since the daemon started.

It's often important to compare the value of [`Max_used_connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Max_used_connections) against the `SHOW VARIABLES` values [`max_connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) and [`max_user_connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections).

Your process ID count from `SHOW PROCESSLIST` isn't very high, which suggests that one of those values may be set unreasonably low, unless MySQL has been restarted since the error last arose.

Answer (score 0):

The "Connections" variable is a connection counter, it is zero when the mysql server starts.
[see the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections)